# How to add condition on TEXT in cell format on excel?

Tags: excel

Edit : I want a data validation with a list that show aliases. Once the user choose something in the list the alias will shown on the cell, but behind the alias I want a value. Like I got an alias "test1" but I need the value "1" when the alias "test1" is choosen in the data vaalidation. Like this I can have a cell with "test1" in it but when I refer to this cell I have a value "1".

I have a blank excel sheet.

- On the cell A1 I put a data validation.
- I choose "list" then I choose the range B1:B3.
- On the cell B1 I write "test1", B2 "test2" and B3 "test3".
- After this, I go to the A1 cell and I right click and access to the "formats cell". After this, I try to make a condition like this :  If on my cell it's written "test1" I display "1", If on my cell it's written "test2" I display "2" and If on my cell it's written "test3" I display "3".

I tried something like this `#;#;#;[@="test1"]1`. But it doesn't work.

So here's my question : Is it possible with excel to create conditionnal format cell based on a text condition instead of number condition ?

Edit 2 : For this problem I need a solution with cell format. Other solution not implying cell format could indeed fix this but I want to do it precisely by this way(if it's possible).

Comment: Why not you write 1,2,3 on B1,B2,B3 cell? Any reason?

Comment: I will edit my post to answer your question and I will do it here to : In fact, I want to have a data validation with ALIAS(kind of nickname) and cells that SHOWS ALIAS but behind those alias when I will refer the A1 cell in another cell like this for example "=A1", it will return the VALUE not the ALIAS.

Comment: "have a cell with "test1" in it" <<- u had set it urself.. the value of that cell IS string 'test1;  | "but when I refer to this cell I have a value "1"."  so.. u mean if it is test1 u want to 'extract' the value 1, n if it is test2 u want to 'extract' the value 2... right?  ==> instead of referring directly.. like this `=A1` .. just refer indirectly like this `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1))` or `=MATCH(A1,{"test1","test2","test3"},0)` will give u value 1.. (pls share if it work/stuck..)

Comment: without knowing your main requirement: why not use a mapping table Text > ID plus `INDEX/MATCH` to retrieve the ID for the according text from A1?

Comment: You both provide a valid solution to this problem but in fact i can't use the index/match method to solve my problem, because this problem is not on excel it's on jedox, but if we solve the problem with cell formating I could use the same solution for jedox

Answer (score 2):

If want to do with VBA then you can follow the below answer;

Other than Column A & B... In Column C; Put the values which you wish to display (1,2,3) in your case in cells "C1:C3"

Now Right Click on the current tab -> then "View Code" & paste this code;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    selectedNa = Target.Value
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("B1:C3"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This Should do the job. Hope this Helps...

Comment: I forgot to mention that VBA isn't allowed to solve this problem sorry :/